# Getting decision path in GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

`sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier` has decision_path method. I was wondering how we can get the same output as decision_path in `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each individual decision tree has the `decision_path` method, and the random forest just [collects those together](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf0ea25d6dd034403370fea552b21a6776bef18/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L286-L299).  You can, more or less, copy that code to get the same thing out of the GBM.